# Publish snapshot and release both to Nexus using maven

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I have followed the blogs [Maven Nexus Deploy](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-deploy-nexus) and [Maven Nexus Release](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-release-nexus) to enable publishing my builds of modular Spring Boot application in Nexus. I am using Nexus opensource and Maven 3.6.0

My plan is to have a setup where I can publish both snapshots and releases based on the maven goal I am running. My current pom contains following details -

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-deploy-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-source-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipSource>true</skipSource>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    <releaseProfiles>releases</releaseProfiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus-releases</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/releases</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
<scm>
    // my scm details
</scm>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>releases</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.8</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-deploy</id>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <serverId>nexus-releases</serverId>
                        <nexusUrl>http://localhost:8081/nexus/</nexusUrl>
                        <skipStaging>true</skipStaging>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

My maven settings.xml contains the server entries -

```
<server>
    <id>nexus-releases</id>
    <username>deployment</username>
    <password>deployment</password>
</server>
<server>
    <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
    <username>deployment</username>
    <password>deployment</password>
</server>
```

When I run command

```
mvn -B release:clean release:prepare release:perform -Darguments="-DskipTests -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true"
```

it works fine and my release build is uploaded to Nexus releases path.

My questions are -

1. Which command should I run so that my snapshot builds are created and uploaded to Nexus snapshots path?
2. If the command is `mvn clean deploy` I tried it and it still doesn't upload snapshot to Nexus. Output for deploy step in above command is -

   [INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) @ company-service ---
   [INFO] Skipping artifact deployment

**EDIT 1 -**

I ran `mvn clean deploy -X` and the logs for deploy plugin are -

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) @ company-service ---
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7852e922]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) artifact = com.exa:company-service:jar:0.0.13-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   (f) attachedArtifacts = []
[DEBUG]   (f) deployAtEnd = false
[DEBUG]   (s) localRepository =       id: local
      url: file:///root/.m2/repository/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => always]

[DEBUG]   (f) offline = false
[DEBUG]   (f) packaging = jar
[DEBUG]   (f) pomFile = /home/dell/repos/exa/exa-microservices/company-service/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.exa:company-service:0.0.13-SNAPSHOT @ /home/dell/repos/exa/exa-microservices/company-service/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) reactorProjects = [MavenProject: com.exa:exa-microservices:0.0.13-SNAPSHOT @ /home/dell/repos/exa/exa-microservices/pom.xml, MavenProject: com.exa:discovery-service:0.0.13-SNAPSHOT @ /home/dell/repos/exa/exa-microservices/discovery-service/pom.xml, MavenProject: com.exa:gateway-service:0.0.13-SNAPSHOT @ /home/dell/repos/exa/exa-microservices/gateway-service/pom.xml, MavenProject: com.exa:common-service:0.0.13-SNAPSHOT @ /home/dell/repos/exa/exa-microservices/common-service/pom.xml, MavenProject: com.exa:auth-service:0.0.13-SNAPSHOT @ /home/dell/repos/exa/exa-microservices/auth-service/pom.xml, MavenProject: com.exa:device-service:0.0.13-SNAPSHOT @ /home/dell/repos/exa/exa-microservices/device-service/pom.xml, MavenProject: com.exa:installer-service:0.0.13-SNAPSHOT @ /home/dell/repos/exa/exa-microservices/installer-service/pom.xml, MavenProject: com.exa:company-service:0.0.13-SNAPSHOT @ /home/dell/repos/exa/exa-microservices/company-service/pom.xml]
[DEBUG]   (f) retryFailedDeploymentCount = 1
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = true
[DEBUG]   (f) updateReleaseInfo = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Skipping artifact deployment
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change the `version` of the asset you're deploying to include `-SNAPSHOT` it will automatically use the snapshot repository.

For example `6.2.0` will go to the release repo when you do `mvn deploy` or your release command.

And `6.2.0-SNAPSHOT` will go to the snapshots repo when you do `mvn deploy` or your release command.

Also remove this:

```
<configuration>
    <skip>true</skip>
</configuration>
```

From you maven-deploy-plugin and you'll be off and running!

Comment: My version tag in pom contains snapshot `<version>0.0.13-SNAPSHOT</version>`. When I run release goal, the version is changed to 0.0.14-SNAPSHOT, release build is created with 0.0.13 and published to release path in Nexus. But the snapshot build is not published to Nexus. When I run mvn clean deploy with snapshot version, nothing happens.

Comment: Can you post the full log for mvn clean deploy? And if that doesn't show much run it with debug on mvn clean deploy -X and post the relevant part of that log

Comment: @abi_pat Added what i think will fix it. You have `<skip>true</skip>` in your deploy config in the pom.

Comment: I am confused then. If I remove the skip configuration, which plugin will execute for deploy goal - Maven deploy or Nexus staging maven? Because I tried removing and then running the release command and it gives me error.

Comment: Error - [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy (default-deploy) on project company-service: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.pct:auth-service:jar:0.0.13 from/to nexus-releases (http://localhost:8081/repository/releases): Failed to transfer file: http://localhost:8081/repository/releases/com/pct/auth-service/0.0.13/auth-service-0.0.13.jar. Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Repository does not allow updating assets: releases.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, both plugins are getting executed and Maven Deploy has already uploaded release build and Nexus plugin is again trying to upload same build and that is giving me error.

Comment: Although, removing skip configuration allows uploading of snapshot builds in mvn deploy